# Correct way to call fillBuffer for AudioBuffer in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

Newbie here. I'm trying to write an audio synthesizer using react/js as the frontend and rust as the backend. The backend would fill the audioBuffer and the framework should reproduce and just fill the buffer with what it's receiving from the backend.

I've tried using this:

```
 const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const myArrayBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(
      2,
      audioCtx.sampleRate/10,
      audioCtx.sampleRate,
    );

 function fillBuffer() {for (let channel = 0; channel < myArrayBuffer.numberOfChannels; channel++) {
      const nowBuffering = myArrayBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
      for (let i = 0; i < myArrayBuffer.length; i++) {
        nowBuffering[i] = genOscillator();
      }
    }
setInterval(fillBuffer, 100)
```

However, the frontend explodes because of the rate at which I'm calling the function, the audio reproduces normally without problems, but it takes too much processing power.

Seeing other audio apps around there that are functional I suppose that there's a better way than what I'm doing. I don't care about using react or pure js as long as it works.

Ty in advance.